# Addition of values of blocks of rows in table

Tags: jquery, addition

I'm not sure how else I could have framed my question, but I have a table with multiple header rows and their respective sub-rows. The sub-rows should add up and set the value of the header rows. How can I do this efficiently?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td> //header row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td> //sub-row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A2</td> //sub-row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td> //header row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>//sub-row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B2</td>//sub-row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td> //header row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1</td> //sub-row
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Sub row `A1` + `A2` should set the total in input of `A`. `B1` + `B2` should add up to `B` and so on.

One way I can think of doing is this way:

```
<tr>
        <td>A</td> //header row
        <td><input type="text" id="a"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td> //sub-row
        <td><input type="text" class="asub"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A2</td> //sub-row
        <td><input type="text" class="asub"/></td>
    </tr>


var finalresult = 0,
            $a = $('.asub'),
            $ares = $('#a');

        $.each($a, function(i) {
            var aVal = parseFloat( $a.eq(i).value() );

            if (aVal) {
                finalresult += aVal;
                $ares.val( finalresult ));
            }

        });
```

But I'll have to do this multiple times for each header row. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). You can access these with [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in jQuery.

An input element could be something like this `<input type="text" data-parent="A" class="sub"/>` . This way you can loop the elements with the `sub` class and read the parent to know which value to increase.

You can put the `data-parent` attribute on the `<tr>` or `<td>`tag if you like.

Hope this helped.

[EDIT]: Added example

```
<tr class="parent-row">
    <td>A</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" id="A" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="child-row">
    <td>A1</td>
    <td><input type="text" data-parent="#A" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="child-row">
    <td>A2</td>
    <td><input type="text" data-parent="#A" /></td>
</tr>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
    $('.child-row').each( function(i) {
        var input = $(this).find('input');
        var parent = input.attr('data-parent'); // Could use the [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

        $(parent).val(parseFloat($(parent).val())+1);
        // If you need to add values of child-rows' input elements you could use the one below
        // $(parent).val(parseFloat($(parent).val())+parseFloat(input.val()));
    });
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @input You allready accepted the answer, is the example still needed ?

Comment: @input I added an example.