# Get data attribute value and set the value of the corresponding element

Tags: jquery, html, addition

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370382/addition-of-values-of-blocks-of-rows-in-table) and based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20370543/100747) given, I have done something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9r79f/1/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Title1</td>
        <td>Title2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="A"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="A" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A2</td> 
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="A"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="A"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="A" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="B"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="B" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="B" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B2</td> 
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="B"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="B"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sub" data-parent="B" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('blur', function() {
        //alert($(this).val());
        calcA($(this));
});

function calcA(param){
        var finalresult = 0,
            $sub = param,
            $value = param.data('parent');

        $.each($sub, function(i) {
            var fiVal = parseFloat( $sub.eq(i).val() );

            if (fiVal) {
                finalresult += fiVal;
                $value.val( finalresult );
            }

        });
}
```

How do I set the value of the first row in `A1` + `A2` to the first row of input in `A` using `data` attributes without repeating the code? And do the same for `B` and so on?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but the context of `$.each` is the current item.  Instead of using `$sub.eq(i).val()`, you can use `this.value` to avoid the redundant jQuery call.

Comment: No problem.  Sorry I'm unable to answer your question.  I haven't used data attributes enough to help.

Comment: Data-attributes solution was suggested by someone in my previous related question. If I can do the addition and add the value to the header row without data-attributes and without repeating for the many rows, then I don't mind using that solution.

Comment: @scrowler, I'm getting the value of the `data-parent` which is `A` but how do I set the total value of the sub rows (`A1` + `A2`) to the corresponding input in header row `A`. I'm lost at that. `$value.val()` is incorrect since Firebug is showing `$value.val() is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either of these things to get `data-parent` attribute:

```
var data_parent_value = $(param).attr('data-parent'); // A or undefined
```

See your console in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9r79f/2/

Comment: I'm getting the value of the `data-parent` which is `A` but how do I set the total value of the sub rows (`A1` + `A2`) to the corresponding input in header row `A`. I'm lost at that. `$value.val()` is incorrect since Firebug is showing `$value.val() is not a function`.